# css background automatically changing animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, sass

pretty new to coding so this is probably a very simple problem but everyone starts somewhere you know, dont judge.

im trying to make an automatically changing background. I'm aware that i dont have the animation attributes / percentages done correctly.. i am currently messing around with it !

question is as soon as i put a linear-gradient on the animation backgrounds the transition ease was null and void. Is this always the case or am i doing it wrong ? thank you

```
header {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
    url("./hero.jpeg") center center/cover;
  animation: animate 30s infinite forwards ease;

  @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
        url(./hero.jpeg) center center/cover;
    }
    20% {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
        url(./hero2.jpeg) center center/cover;
    }
    40% {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
        url(./hero3.jpeg) center center/cover;
    }
    60% {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
        url(./hero4.jpeg) center center/cover;
    }
    80% {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
        url(./hero5.jpeg) center center/cover;
    }
    100% {
      background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
        url(./hero.jpeg) center center/cover;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The linear gradient should have at least two values, not one, and you shouldn't have a comma separating the two backgrounds. You didn't give me two values, so I just removed the gradient for the transparent color.

**Wrong**

```
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)),
    url(./hero.jpeg) center center/cover;
```

**Correct**

```
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
    url(./hero.jpeg) center center/cover;
```

```css
header {
  height: 100vh;
  animation: animate 30s infinite forwards ease;
}

 @keyframes animate {
    0% {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200") center center/cover;
    }
    20% {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        url("https://picsum.photos/id/2/200/200") center center/cover;
    }
    40% {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        url("https://picsum.photos/id/3/200/200") center center/cover;
    }
    60% {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        url("https://picsum.photos/id/4/200/200") center center/cover;
    }
    80% {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        url("https://picsum.photos/id/5/200/200") center center/cover;
    }
    100% {
      background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
        url("https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200") center center/cover;
    }
  }
```

```html
<header></header>
```